# Regular Expression, dynamic number

Tags: regex

The regular expression which I have provided will select the string `72719`.

Regular expression:

```
(?<=bdfg34f;\d{4};)\d{0,9}
```

Text sample:

```
vfhnsirf;5234;72159;2;668912;28032009;4;
bdfg34f;8467;72719;7;6637912;05072009;7;
b5g342sirf;234;72119;4;774582;20102009;3;
```

How can I rewrite the expression to select that string even when the number `8467;` is changed to `84677;` or `846777;` ? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't use any language at this point, I'm using http://regexr.com?2tikn for testing purposes. I just wanted to ask if it is possible to rewrite the above expression to show the exact number "72719" but with the another quantity of numbers before or not.

Comment: The reason I ask is because the answer depends upon whether or not your language supports: _variable length lookbehind_ (most don't). If it does (.NET), then James Kyburz's solution will work. If it doesn't then you will need to use a solution like the one I proposed.

Comment: @ridgerunner: I prefer to call it *unbounded* lookbehind, and AFAIK it's only supported by .NET and [JGSoft](http://www.regular-expressions.info/jgsoft.html).  But some flavors (notably Perl and PCRE) offer the match point reset operator, `\K`, as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when asking a regex question, you should always specify which language you are using. 
Assuming that the language you are using does not support variable length lookbehind (and most don't), here is a solution which will work. Your original expression uses a fixed-length lookbehind to match the pattern preceding the value you want. But now this preceding text may be of variable length so you can't use a look behind. This is no problem. Simply match the preceding text normally and capture the portion that you want to keep in a capture group. Here is a tested PHP code snippet which grabs all values from a string, capturing each value into capture group `$1`:

```php
$re = '/^bdfg34f;\d{4,};(\d{0,9})/m';
if (preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches)) {
    $values = $matches[1];
}
```

The changes are:

- Removed the lookbehind group.
- Added a start of line anchor and set multi-line mode.
- Changed the `\d{4}` *"exactly four"* to `\d{4,}` *"four or more"*.
- Added a capture group for the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I usually describe "fields" in a regex:

`[^;]+;[^;]+;([^;]+);`

This means "stuff that isn't semi-colon, followed by a semicolon", which describes each field. Do that twice. Then the third time, select it.

You may have to tweak the syntax for whatever language you are doing this regex in.

Also, if this is just a data file on disk and you are using GNU tools, there's a much easier way to do this:

`cat file | cut -d";" -f 3`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Interesting solution using GNU tools, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

to match the first number with a minimum of 4 digits

```
(?<=bdfg34f;\d{4,};)\d{0,9}
```

and to match the first number with 1 or more length

```
(?<=bdfg34f;\d+;)\d{0,9}
```

or to match the first number only if the length is between 4 and 6

```
(?<=bdfg34f;\d{4,6};)\d{0,9}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've tested it on http://regexhero.net/tester/ and now I see it working on .NET. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple text parsing problem that probably doesn't mandate the use of regular expressions.

You could take the input line by line and split on ';', i.e. (in php, I have no idea what you're doing)

```
foreach (explode("\n", $string) as $line) {
    $bits = explode(";", $line);
    echo $bits[3]; // third column
}
```

If this is indeed in a file and you happen to be using PHP, using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) would be much better though.

Anyway, context is missing, but the bottom line is I don't think you should be using regular expressions for this.